# Overlapping content and elastic width issues CSS

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design

I'm sort of new at Web Design, I'm getting there, though. But I'm still having trouble with elastic layouts and floats. I think that's where my problem with this page lies but I'm too inexperienced to understand it.

Here's my problems illustrated: 
https://img.skitch.com/20120327-nwrm3t1u8cwppnwnegw8f2q7st.jpg

Here's a fiddle with my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/C3Dw2/1/

This is what it SHOULD look like:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/register_13.jpg

I also want to have the right scrolling section fit in it's parent div. Right now, it's flowing out of it.

Ugh.

Any help would be awesome.

---

EDIT

The only issue remaining now is the icons not staying in their parent divs. 
http://jsfiddle.net/xehMG/2/

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. Too much to untangle. You seem to have everything floated left without really knowing why. You are using an unordered list, which usually has the `li`'s floated, but instead you are floating the `p` tags inside the `li`. You also use percents for positioning/margins which is doomed for failure and have centered text set on the main body tag which is going to make positioning all this stuff difficult as well. I would break this question up into much simpler questions and repost so that you actually understand the mechanics behind the question you are asking.

Comment: Sooo... maybe I should just start the whole thing over?

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: what is the overlapping issues dear please tell me i can solve it for u.

Comment: When the browser is shrunk to about 900x600 pixels, the jump menu is poking into the right_col with the search results.

Comment: I managed to fix the jump menu. The issue now is the icons won't stay in their parent divs, .result1 and .result2 I really think part of my problem is not understanding floats, clears and how they work with divs. http://jsfiddle.net/xehMG/2/

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle for code and demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3Dw2/4

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C3Dw2/4/embedded/result/

see screen shot for output:

[image]

Comment: Could you let me know what my major issue was in the search bar? What do you think I need to better understand?

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-height` on each of the elements that u've given `height` and `width` in percentage.Percentage will be effective only when the resolution is big enf to encompass ur children elements.

If you want to use percentages - note the min-width required for their children and set that min-width for its parent.Also use `overflow:hidden|scroll|auto` as a fall back to control the overflow of the children out of its parent.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I'm not sure I'm following. "Percentage will be effective only when the resolution is big enf to encompass ur children elements." Could you expand on this or maybe provide a link to an article that explains this? I'm sorry I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: try putting ur head inside a box which's smaller than that box -- not quite possible isnt it.. ??.. that's what i mean.. when ur `textBox` and other elements have a width say `100px` - u cant fit it insite an element which is say `80px` -- ur elements can be 80px if u've given the width in percentage without `min-width`(which should be set to 100px)..